# Can I include the included in a UML use case diagram?

Tags: uml, relationship, use-case

In [UML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language#Diagrams_overview), when drawing a [use case diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case_diagram), can I include the already included use case? (Or extend the already extended use case?)

Does it make sense? I have such a situation where I think I can include B in A and include C in B; where A, B, C are all use cases.

```
A ----------------> B ----------------> C
    <<include>>          <<include>>
```

Dose it technically make sense?

Comment: I'd say: If you think it better reflects the relationship between your use cases and the people who is supposed to read those diagrams understand it correctly, then go for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, it is possible to do what you mentioned, if it fits your scenario. But just remember, use 'include' usually to abstract sequences of steps out of the primary Use Cases that are helpful to the analyst to avoid repetition. This means it comes into picture after you have completed at least the first cut basic flows for all your main Use Cases. The main purpose is to simplify your use-case diagram, not to complicate it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether the usecase A is being called from C directly and not within the scope of B. If A is being used by C directly, then it makes sense to draw that in your C use case and qualify A as included. Else you could ignore.